# Creating a new admin user in activeadmin

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using active admin on rails 4, I white-listed the parameters for admin users in the controller using:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
 controller do
  def permitted_params
   params.permit(:admin_user => [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end
 end
end
```

but when I try to add a new user, I get the error "cannot be blank" on the email and password fields. The logs read the following:

```
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, admin_user, commit
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you are here because of the utf8, authenticity_token, commit then I would suggest this solution is not related to this issue https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2595

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.

Changing

```
params.permit(:admin_user => [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
```

to

```
params.permit(:user => [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
```

solved the issue. `devise` in active admin creates model with name `user` and in active admin user model, its mentioned as `admin_user`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happenning because i had a validation for an associated record on that model. Disabling that validation fixes it, will need to check how to disable validations for active admin only.